# Do not let the viewer go to the first page systematically

Tags: pdf, preview, emacs, latex

I edit tex files with `Emacs` under `Mac OS X 10.10.1`, compile tex pdf and view it with `Preview`.

The problem is that each time the code is modified and re-compiled, the viewer systematically goes to the first page of the pdf. Ideally, I want to stay in the same page as before, where is probably the modification.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Will changing to another viewer do the trick?

PS: I used to do this under Ubuntu with `evince` and `okular`, that worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In Preview there is only a setting that let it start on the page that it was last used, but that is not necessarily the page with the modification made by emacs.

Comment: I did tick the setting `Start on the last viewed page`, it did not help. Apparently, each time the pdf is re-generated, this information is lost...

Comment: That may be due to the OS X version? Which OS X are you using?